# Beginner Question: trying to join 2-3 queries SQL Lite

Tags: sql

I'm a beginner with SQL but i seem to be stuck.

So im trying to find the transaction with highest transaction amount, then the transaction with the lowest transaction amount, and then the average of the transaction amounts. But then display all these in one table. I seem to be stuck or dont understand the JOIN function in this scenario, I can query all these separately but cant seem to get these to display on one table.

This is what i was able to get for the separate queries, but i cant seem to join these correctly...

--Max Transaction

```
SELECT TransactionAmount 
FROM TransactionData 
ORDER BY TransactionAmount DESC LIMIT 1;
```

--Min Transaction

```
SELECT TransactionAmount 
FROM TransactionData
ORDER BY TransactionAmount ASC LIMIT 1;
```

--Average Transaction

```
SELECT avg(TransactionAmount) FROM TransactionData;
```

Comment: Did you find the answer below helpful? If so, you can mark the answer accepted to bring closure to your question. It's your choice whether you want to mark an answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want 3 columns to be shown, you can do this:

```
SELECT
  min(TransactionAmount) as Min_Amount
  , avg(TransactionAmount) as Avg_Amount
  , max(TransactionAmount) as Max_Amount
FROM TransactionData 
ORDER BY TransactionAmount;
```

If you want to show them one underneath the other, you can do this:

```
SELECT 'Min Amount' as Type, min(TransactionAmount) as Amount FROM TransactionData
union all
SELECT 'Avg Amount' as Type, avg(TransactionAmount) as Amount FROM TransactionData
union all
SELECT 'Max Amount' as Type, max(TransactionAmount) as Amount FROM TransactionData;
```